# How can i make sure the user selects something from a Select list without using onSubmit - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Basically i have a simple form in HTML. I want to validate user inputs but dont want to use onSubmit as its not 'live' feedback.

```
*Title:
<select name="title">
    <option value="Select..">Select</option>
    <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
    <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
    <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
</select><br />
*First Name: <input type="text" name="first"/>
```

I want to use javascript so when a user clicks the 'First Name' input box and if they haven't selected the 'Title', the browser forces them to select the title before continuing. `onChange` doesnt work for obvious reasons.

Comment: How about an onblur event on the first and/or last name fields?

Comment: i can do that but how would that satisfy the title field? @jeff

Comment: and what about trying to write some code then come back ? Your idea is good, just try it.

Comment: i have written the whole code for onSubmit but then i realised it wasnt good enough for something like this. I have also tried onChange that doesnt work because you arent changing anything. I have tried onFocus and onClick, they only work when the Title box is clicked, not the First name input box. @Bartdude

Comment: Well, you could use the `onfocus` event of each other field of your form : if they enter another field before having selected anything, you can display an alert message. But to me, the easiest would be to display only the select field at first, and show the other ones only when a value was selected...

Comment: You could set the `input` disabled, and enable it in `onchange` handler for `select`, only if the `select.selectedIndex > 0`. This model allows you to clear the `input`, if user deselects the `title`.

Answer (score 1):

This would trigger when a user deselects an input in the form or the dropdown list.

```
$('input, select').onblur(function(){
    /*Run your checks here*/
});
```

To check whether they have actually selected an option, I would use something like this...

```
$('input, select').onblur(function(){
    var text = $('select').find(":selected").text();
    if(text == 'Select'){
        //Show error
    }
});
```